# packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex - duplicate entry "Escaper.class"

Tags: android

How does this happen when I try to deploy? In what library is this class ?

**Note:** It compiles and builds just fine, but this error shows up only when I try to deploy.

```
:myProject:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':myProject:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/gdata/util/common/base/Escaper.class
```

These are the dependencies in my project, required by 4 different modules:

```
compile files('libs/gson-1.7.1.jar')
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.1.1.jar')
compile files('libs/icu4j-4_8_1_1.jar')
compile files('libs/signpost-core-1.2.1.1.jar')
compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-3.0.5.jar')

compile files('libs/comscore.jar')
compile files('libs/javabase64-1.3.1.jar')
compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalytics.jar')
compile files('libs/urbanairship-lib-2.1.2.jar')

compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'

compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
```

Comment: Error log says that your two dependencies contains same "Escaper" class..!! And i tried to find which both and figured that it is 'Gson' and 'sign-post-core' .. I added both in my gradle but it works fine.

Comment: I think you should add 
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:1.7.1'
    compile 'oauth.signpost:signpost-core:1.2.1.1' in your dependencies not in libs folder.. May be it will solve your problem..!!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion... I will try it in a few hours.

Comment: that fixed it ! getting rid of libs was key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like `Mamata Gelanee` said in the comments, the solution is to use maven repos instead of .jar's in /libs.

I've gotten rid of all jar's in my /libs folder and replaced it with maven repos and now it all builds and deploys fine.